# Why does this destructor not have to delete the class object?

Tags: c++, class, destructor, new-operator, delete-operator

I'm a beginner at programming and learning about classes. I'm following an [archived online course](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-096-introduction-to-c-january-iap-2011/assignments/MIT6_096IAP11_assn03.pdf) and making a destructor for the `class Polygon`.

The [answer given](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-096-introduction-to-c-january-iap-2011/assignments/MIT6_096IAP11_sol03.pdf) has `~Polygon` without a line to delete the `PointArray points`, only containing a line to decrement `numPolygons`.
I would assume that `~PointArray` is activated somehow to delete the `points`.

- Why do we not have to `delete[] &points;` in `~Polygon`?
- If my assumption is correct, when and how does PointArray's destructor go into effect?
- How would having `delete[] &points;` in `~Polygon` affect the program?

The following simplified code compiles under Visual Studio Community 2015.

Thank you!

```
class Point {
private: int x, y;
public:
    Point(int x = 0, int y = 0) {
        this->x = x;        // initializes (*this).x with x
        this->y = y;        // initializes (*this).y with x
    }
    // other member functions...
};

class PointArray {
    int len;
    Point *points;
public:
    PointArray() {
        len = 0;
        points = new Point[0];
    }
    PointArray(const Point copyPoints[], const int size) {
        points = new Point[size];
        len = size;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) points[i] = copyPoints[i];
    }
    PointArray(const PointArray &pv) {
        len = pv.len;
        points = new Point[len];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) points[i] = pv.points[i];
    }
    ~PointArray() {
        delete[] points;
    }
    // other member functions...
};

class Polygon {
protected:
    PointArray points;
    static int numPolygons; // tracks # of Polygon instances/objects
public:
    Polygon(const Point pointArr[], const int numPoints)
        : points(pointArr, numPoints) {     // initializes internal PointArray
        ++numPolygons;                      // +1 (initialized)
    }
    Polygon(const PointArray &pa)
        : points(pa) {                  // initializes internal PointArray with arg
        ++numPolygons;
    }
    ~Polygon() {
        //delete[] &points;
        --numPolygons;
    }
};

int main() { return 0;  }
```

Comment: it looks like you are reaching into undefined behavior with `points = new Point[size];`

Comment: `PointsArray` should have an overloaded `operator=` member function to be compliant with [rule of three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)).

Comment: @DanielA.White What do you mean?

Comment: @PaulRooney Thanks! I didn't learn about copy assignment operators yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your assumption is basically correct. Here are a couple of notes:

- `delete` (and `delete[]`) are only used to delete **pointers** to variables allocated on the heap, using the `new` operator. In the `Polygon` class, the `PointArray` member isn't a pointer, it's just a member object entirely contained within the `Polygon` object.
- You're correct that the destructor for `PointArray` is responsible for deleting the `Point *points` array in the `PointArray` class. What happens is that, when the destructor of a "parent" object (like `Polygon`) is called, it automatically recursively calls the destructors for all of its member objects (and all of *their* member objects, etc.) Here's a relevant section from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor):

> For both user-defined or implicitly-defined destructors, after the body of the destructor is executed, **the compiler calls the destructors for all non-static non-variant members of the class, in reverse order of declaration**, then it calls the destructors of all direct non-virtual base classes in reverse order of construction (which in turn call the destructors of their members and their base classes, etc), and then, if this object is of most-derived class, it calls the destructors of all virtual bases.

So, the sequence in this simple case is:

1. The `~Polygon` destructor is called and is completely executed, decrementing `numPolygons`.
2. The `~PointArray` destructor is called on `points`. This deletes the underlying array owned by the `PointArray` object.

If you were to delete the `PointArray.points` pointer in `~Polygon`, the array would get deleted twice (once by `~Polygon` and once by `~PointArray`), which is undefined behavior but will likely result in a crash.

**Edit to add**: as a further comment, in modern C++, you would likely want to use a "smart pointer" like [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), rather than a "raw" pointer like your tutorial is doing. That frees you from the burden of this kind of low-level memory management, since the smart pointer class will handle all of the details of deleting the array when it goes out of scope.

**Second edit**: @user4581301 has an even better suggestion, which is to use [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) rather than bothering with pointers at all. The `vector` class will handle all the underlying memory management details for you. It will also dynamically grow and shrink to handle variably-sized arrays of objects, rather than being constrained to a fixed size.

Comment: Recommendation: Tack on a note about using `std::vector` or similar containers rather than dynamically allocated arrays even if protected by smart pointers if only because they handle the Rules of Three and five  much more easily.

Comment: Thank you! That is very helpful.